# How to fix accessibility issues related to Samsung's Voice Assistant?

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm using AccessibilityDelegateCompat to implement fine accessibility in application.

I found following issues on Samsung devices with android < 12.

1. No one phone understands and read state defined by call of setStateDescription.
2. The half of phones doesn't understand and read setRoleDescription.

Out MinSdk is 24.

I have tried to search solution but failed.

Do any one know to to fix it? Or may be you know the Samsung related accessibility development guide?